# rails working dates and string concatenation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting undefined method for nill from the last line of this snippet in my controller

```
@showday = params["showdate(3i)"]
@showmonth = params["showdate(2i)"]
@showmonth_int = @showmonth.to_i
@showmonth = Date::MONTHNAMES[@showmonth_int]
@showyear = params["showdate(1i)"]
@showdate = @showmonth << " " << @showday << ", " << @showyear
```

Comment: Why don't you just parse the date out of the parameters? Can you paste how the date looks like in the parameters in your log?

Comment: Just assign the date param to a model the way its supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) here

```
@showday = params.fetch('showdate(3i)', '')
@showmonth = Date::MONTHNAMES[params.fetch('showdate(2i)', 0).to_i]
@showyear = params.fetch("showdate(1i)", '')
@showdate = @showmonth << " " << @showday << ", " << @showyear
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use string interpolation, something like this

```
@showdate = "#{@showmonth} #{@showday}, #{@showyear}"
```

you can just insert into #{} any ruby code and will print into the string, this is a better and simple way to "concatenate" a string